# Anylogic wearhouse - how to combine two agents to create one final agent

Tags: anylogic

Good afternoon to everyone,

I have a problem with the software AnyLogic. I have to do a program that is able to combine two agents (two different semifinished) to create one final agent (final product). The problem is that the two semifinished have different production time, so I need a function that is able to accept one agent (the first semifinished), than to wait for the second agent and at the end to generate one final agent from the previous two agents (semifinished). How it's possible to do this? I have already tried with the function "Combine" without any success.

Comment: I'm assuming the semi-finished materials will be in a queue (simulating a warehouse or buffer). When you have the 20 agents of each you can trigger a **cyclic event** that occurs every X minutes. In the action of that event, remove one agent of each type from the queue and create a final product. Send that created final product through an **Enter** block that you will connect to wherever you need your final product to go to.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the "Assember" object from the process library. Speciy how many agents of type A and B you need (1 each in your case). The assember will create a new agent type (you need to specify it) from the 2 incoming agents once it has got 1 of each.

Also check the help on the Assembler, you can do lots of fine-tuning with it.

cheers

Comment: The problem of Assembler is that it create a queue of agents, and I don't want queue in my model. The main problem of my model is the following: after the stock of the two different kind of products (product1 and product2) in the Palletrack, I want that every 20 minutes one product1 and one product2 combine to form one final product. So I want that each time that one product1 is picked up, also one product2 is pickek up. Is it possible to do this? Combine and Assembler blocks create a queue that I don't want to have..